# C# cancellation tokens as task second argument

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, cancellation-token

How can I cancel a long running task by forwarding the token inside the task rather than inside the method the task is calling?

My code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource token = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Stopwatch stop = new Stopwatch();
        stop.Start();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myLongTask(6000), token.Token);

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.SpinWait(1000);
            if (stop.ElapsedMilliseconds > 3000)
            {
                token.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void myLongTask(int time)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Console.WriteLine("Task started");
        while (true)
        { }
        Console.WriteLine("Task ended");
    }
}
```

This task never gets cancelled. If I forward the token within `myLongTask()` method I can listen continuously if the cancellation was triggered, however, I am not sure... How can you do it in this way?

Comment: cancellation is *co-operative*. By that nature, code has to be written to be *aware* of the cancellation token(s) it should be respecting.

Comment: Is there no way to do it otherwise?

Comment: The alternative is pre-emption, as exemplified by e.g. `Thread.Abort` - but it can easily lead to difficult-to-clean-up states - which is why pretty well any modern approach to cancellation adopts a co-operative style. So, no, I wouldn't recommend an alternative - make code that needs to be cancellable aware of cancellation tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the state of the token yourself, for example:

```
public static void myLongTask(int time, CancellationToken token)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine("Task started");
    while (true)
    { 
      token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Task ended");
}
```

The reason for this, as mentioned in the comments, it that cancellation is a co-operative action. It it wasn't then the framework would have to force your task to stop, and this could leave your application in an undesirable state. By checking yourself you have full control over what it means to cancel an operation.

Comment: I know...I would like to find a way to do it outside of the scope of that function

Comment: @Norgul how do you want your function to behave in case of a cancellation? The Idea of the CancellationToken is to provide a defined cancellation (which means the Workload function needs to know about the token and handle it).

Comment: I would like it to break the continuous loop and stop execution with the exception

Comment: @Norgul You **have** to do that with your code because none of outside class could change your code in such way.