# C# check for cancellation token during for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, cancellation, cancellation-token

I don't fully understand cancellation tokens, but I believe that is what I need to use.

I have a listbox full of file paths, and a method (`ProcesstListSort`) which goes through each file path in the list box and executes different methods based on file type. `ProcessListSort` is called from another method, that is called from a button click. I'm trying to run `BeginEverything` in a background task because it was locking up the UI. What is the best place to implement cancellation token checking in this scenario?

This button click starts the process:

```cs
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task task1 = new Task(BeginEverything);
    task1.Start();
    await task1;
}
```

Which launches this:

```cs
public void BeginEverything()
{
    CreateThing1();
    CreateThing2();
    ProcessListSort();  //This is the one I think I need to interrupt because it's the longest
    CreateThing3();
    CreateThing4();
}
```

Which launches the longest task here (sorting files and executing other methods based on file type, passing the file path to those other methods):

```cs
public void ProcessListSort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string p = listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
        FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(p);

        if (p.EndsWith(".zip"))
        {
            Method1(p);
        }
        if (p.EndsWith(".txt"))
        {
            Method2(p);
        }
        if ((attr & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            Method3(p);
        }
        else
        {
            Method4(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Immediate cancellation after clicking a Cancel button would be ideal, but I would settle for just cancelling between each file that is processed in `ProcessedListSort`. I think the problem is I am running methods from other methods and I'm not sure were the cancellation check needs to be applied. The closest I have gotten was where it saw the cancellation token, but only "cancelled" after everything had already executed.

Any other suggestions or links to alternate ways of doing this are greatly appreciated. I know I'm doing plenty of things incorrectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# cancellation tokens as task second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341084/c-sharp-cancellation-tokens-as-task-second-argument)

Comment: [Task Cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)

Comment: That looks like it would work, but it didn't mesh with what I had as smoothly and I kept running into problems - I'm sure just because I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to create a `CancellationTokenSource` and then pass the `CancellationToken` to the methods you want to cancel.

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts =
        new CancellationTokenSource( );

public async void OnClick( object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    // Disable your button here.

    var token = _cts.Token;
    try { await Task.Run( ( ) => LongRunning( token ), token ); }
    catch( OperationCanceledException )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Task was cancelled" );
    }            
    // Enable your button here.
}

public void OnCancel( object sender, EventArgs args )
{
    _cts.Cancel( );
    _cts.Dispose( );
    _cts = new CancellationTokenSource( );
}

public void LongRunning( CancellationToken token = default )
{
    // You can either check for cancellation
    // or throw if cancelled.

    // If cancellation is requested this will throw an
    // OperationCanceledException.
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested( );

    // If you don't want to throw you can check the
    // CancellationToken to see if cancellation was requested.
    if ( token.IsCancellationRequested )
        return;
   
    // You can also pass the token to other methods that
    // you want to observe cancellation.
    AnotherLongRunning( token );
}
```

Comment: I think I'm making progress with this, but what does OnCancel do above? It doesn't seem to link to anything. Right now, I have it kind of working except when I hit the Cancel button it throws what seems like a random error (System.IO.IOException: 'The file 'C:\Test\Testing\sample.zip' already exists.'
), but at least it's happening when the button is pushed. Do i just catch that error somehow, and that will interrupt the rest of the processes?

Comment: `OnCancel` is a `Button` event handler. Let's say the user clicks on a start `Button` on your UI. The event handler for that `click` event is the `OnClick` method. When the `Button` is clicked the event handler `OnClick` is executed and it calls the `LongRunning` method. Now let's say the user wants to cancel the operation, the user would click a cancel `Button` on the UI. The handler for that click event is the `OnCancel` method. When the cancel `Button` is clicked the event handler `OnCancel` is called. From the `OnCancel` method 'Cancel' is called, thus cancelling the `CancellationTokens`

Comment: Thank you. That cleared it up. It took a little more wiggling things around and I don't think it's working exactly as yours but it is working! For example, I don't think it's catching the exception as designed, and I tried to replace `Console.WriteLine( "Task was cancelled" );` with a `MessageBox.Show` and it wasn't showing it. So something is off but I'm catching the token elsewhere I guess? I'll keep testing but so far so good. Thanks again.

Comment: If you have `try catch` else where and you're catching `Exception` then the `OperationCanceledException` would be caught before it reaches the exception handler in the `OnClick` method. I'd suggest either catching specific exceptions, using multiple catch blocks or using an exception filter: `catch ( Exception ex ) when ( !( ex is OperationCanceledException )  ) {  }`